# Monaca: How to share an app with testers on the Basic plan?

Tags: monaca

The Monaca [documentation](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/manual/monaca_ide/interface/) states that Basic plans allow for inviting users to join a project as testers. However, I can find no docs on how to do so, and clicking **Share Project** returns "Please upgrade your plan in order to use this feature."

Is there a way to share an app with testers without upgrading to a paid plan?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood. As stated in the documentation,

> However, if your usage plan is Basic or Personal, you can only chat and join a team as a Tester

You can join as a tester but you can't share a project. In other words, you can be invited to join a project as a tester. Personal or Basic account has no team management feature (share projects and invite people into the projects). Please refer to [here](https://monaca.mobi/en/pricing) for more information regarding the privilege of each account type.

Comment: Ah, so a user with a paid plan can invite a user with a Basic plan. That makes sense. Thanks!